# spring security and facebook authentication not working

Tags: facebook, spring, spring-security

I want to use facebook login + DB authentication in my application which uses Spring Security.

So I have added one fb button in index.jsp page which sends request like,

```
function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
        console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.' + response.email);
        window.location = "<%=request.getContextPath()%>/j_spring_facebook_security_check";
    });
}
```

applicationContext-Security.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
    //spring security 3.
    <security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" access-denied-page="/accessDenied.jsp">
        <security:form-login login-page="/index.jsp"
            default-target-url="/jsp/home.jsp"
            authentication-failure-handler-ref="authenticationFailureHandler"/>

        <security:intercept-url pattern="/jsp/listInBetweenPlaces.jsp"
            access="permitAll" />

        <security:intercept-url pattern="/jsp/home.jsp"
            access="permitAll" />

        <security:intercept-url pattern="/index.jsp"
            access="permitAll" />

        <security:intercept-url pattern="/jsp/*"
            access="isAuthenticated()" />

        <security:logout logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout" logout-success-url="/index.jsp?logout=success" 
            invalidate-session="true"  />

        <security:custom-filter before="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER"
            ref="facebookAuthenticationFilter" />
</security:http>

    <bean id="facebookAuthenticationFilter" class="org.springframework.security.facebook.FacebookAuthenticationFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>

        <property  name = "authenticationSuccessHandler">
            <bean  class = "org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
                <property  name = "defaultTargetUrl"  value = "/jsp/home.jsp"  />
                <property  name = "alwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl"  value = "true"  />
            </bean>
        </property>

        <property  name = "authenticationFailureHandler">
            <bean  class = "org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
                <property  name = "defaultFailureUrl"  value = "/fb/failure.jsp"  />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="authenticationProviderFacebook" class="org.springframework.security.facebook.FacebookAuthenticationProvider">
        <property name="roles" value="ROLE_FACEBOOK_USER" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="facebookHelper"  class="org.springframework.security.facebook.FacebookHelper">
        <property  name="apiKey"  value="my_api_key"  />
        <property  name="secret"  value="my_secret_key"  />
    </bean>

    <bean id="customUserDetailsService" class="com.onmobile.carpool.authentication.CustomUserDetailsService">
        <!--  <property name="carpoolService" ref="carpoolServiceImpl" /> -->
    </bean>

    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService">
            <security:password-encoder hash="md5" />
        </security:authentication-provider>
        <security:authentication-provider ref="authenticationProviderFacebook">
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>
</beans>
```

FacebookAuthenticationFilter.java:

```
public class FacebookAuthenticationFilter extends
                AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter implements
                ApplicationContextAware {

    public static final String DEFAULT_FILTER_PROCESS_URL = "/j_spring_facebook_security_check";
    private FacebookHelper facebookHelper = null ;
    private ApplicationContext ctx;
    protected FacebookAuthenticationFilter() {
        super(DEFAULT_FILTER_PROCESS_URL);
    }

    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req,
                        HttpServletResponse res) throws AuthenticationException,
                        IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

        if(facebookHelper == null){
            facebookHelper = (FacebookHelper) ctx
                    .getBean("facebookHelper");
        }

        Long uid = null;
        String sessionkey = null ;
        try {
            uid = facebookHelper.getLoggedInUserId(request, response);
            sessionkey = facebookHelper.lookupSessionKey(request);
        } catch (FacebookUserNotConnected e) {
            throw new AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException(
                                        "Facebook user not connected", e);
        }

        FacebookAuthenticationToken token = new FacebookAuthenticationToken(uid);
        token.setSessionkey(sessionkey);
        token.setDetails(authenticationDetailsSource.buildDetails(request));

        AuthenticationManager authenticationManager = getAuthenticationManager();
        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager
                                .authenticate(token);

        return authentication;
    }

    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ctx)
                        throws BeansException {
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    public FacebookHelper getFacebookHelper() {
        return facebookHelper;
    }

    public void setFacebookHelper(FacebookHelper facebookHelper) {
        this.facebookHelper = facebookHelper;
    }

}
```

I am always getting problem with this call:

```
 uid = facebookHelper.getLoggedInUserId(request, response);
```

Details of `getLoggedInUserId` in FacebookHelper.java:

```
public Long getLoggedInUserId(HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response) throws FacebookUserNotConnected {

    FacebookWebappHelper<Document> facebook = new FacebookWebappHelper<Document>(
                        request, response, apiKey, secret);
    Long uid = facebook.getUser();

    if (uid == null)
            throw new FacebookUserNotConnected(
                            "Facebook user id could not be obtained");
    return uid;
}
```

Below line always evaluates to null because of which it throws exception:

```
Long uid = facebook.getUser();
```

I took Facebook Related classes from link below,

[https://code.google.com/p/spring-security-facebook/source/browse/trunk/src/?r=4#src%2Fmain%2Fjava%2Forg%2Fspringframework%2Fsecurity%2Ffacebook](https://code.google.com/p/spring-security-facebook/source/browse/trunk/src/?r=4#src/main/java/org/springframework/security/facebook)

My need is to keep user can either login to my app through DB check or through FB authentication.

I am not able to go ahead with this, can some one please point out What I am missing.
I am always getting redirected to failure.jsp. 
Is there any thing i need to enable in FB account? 
Or I am passing some incorrect data from UI to Filter?

I am not able to find complete tutorial anywhere for this, can someone point out the correct link.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar in a recent app I've been working on. I looked into using the Spring-Oauth project to perform the oauth authentication but realized later on that spring-oauth requires you to already be authenticated in your application, and all other solutions I found online were out-dated.

After struggling for a couple days this is what I ended up doing. I'm using JSF with PrimeFaces in my app, but I hope it'll give you an idea. The approach is to initially use the Facebook Javascript API to perform the Facebook authentication for you. There are plenty of examples on the Facebook page on how to do this:

### login.xhtml - Facebook API section

```
...
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
  // Here we specify what we do with the response anytime this event occurs. 
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    //a user has logged in to the app
    var responseToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
    var responseUserId = response.authResponse.accessToken;
    loginJS([{name:'token', value: responseToken}, {name:'name', value: responseUserId}]);                      
  } 
});
...
```

Somewhere in the body of you page also add this:

```
<p:remoteCommand name="loginJS" action="#{userBean.facebookLogin}" immediate="true"  process="@this" />;
```

The *p:remoteCommand* calls the managed bean (userBean) facebookLogin function. This function retrieves from the request the two parameters (userId, token). In your case, all you need to do is call your "login" servlet from the javascript and pass the two parameters as part of the request.

### UserBean.java

```
public String facebookLogin(){
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    Map<String, String> map = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
    String userToken = map.get("token");
    String name = map.get("name");

    if(logger.isLoggable(Level.FINEST)){
        logger.finest("Login attempt via facebook. Token: "+ userToken);
    }

    Authentication auth = new FacebookTokenAuthentication(userToken, name);

    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);

    return "home?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

### FacebookTokenAuthentication.java

```
public class FacebookTokenAuthentication implements Authentication {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4218179259794454698L;
    private String token;
    private String name;

    public FacebookTokenAuthentication(String token, String name) {
        this.token = token;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>(0);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getCredentials() {
        return token;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getDetails() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getPrincipal() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAuthenticated() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void setAuthenticated(boolean isAuthenticated)
            throws IllegalArgumentException {
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

### FacebookAuthenticationProvider.java

The last part is to create a facebook authentication provider. This Authentication provider will call the facebook API to obtain the user information and lookup the user in your databases that matches. You can map the facebook id of the user in your database or you can use the email address to find the user. For this part I used spring-social FacebookTemplate to obtain the facebook profile information.

```
public class FacebookAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger
            .getLogger(FacebookAuthenticationProvider.class.getName());

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider#
     * authenticate(org.springframework.security.core.Authentication)
     */
    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication auth)
            throws AuthenticationException {
        Authentication resultAuth = null;
        if (logger.isLoggable(Level.FINEST)) {
            logger.finest("Attempting to authenticate user via the FacebookAuthenticationProvider.");
        }

        if (auth.isAuthenticated()) {
            return auth;
        }

        if (auth instanceof FacebookTokenAuthentication) {

            FacebookTokenAuthentication fbAuth = (FacebookTokenAuthentication) auth;
            String token = (fbAuth.getCredentials() != null) ? fbAuth
                    .getCredentials().toString() : null;

            if (logger.isLoggable(Level.FINEST)) {
                logger.finest("Creating facebook template. Token:" + token);
            }

            FacebookTemplate fbTemplate = new FacebookTemplate(token);

            FacebookProfile userProfile = fbTemplate.userOperations()
                    .getUserProfile();

            // LOOKUP THE USER IN YOUR DATABASE
            User user = //ADD CUSTOM USER LOOKUP HERE;

            resultAuth = new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken(user, token);
            resultAuth.setAuthenticated(true);
        } else {

            throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid credentials.");
        }

        return resultAuth;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see
     * org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider#supports
     * (java.lang.Class)
     */
    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> auth) {
        return auth.equals(FacebookTokenAuthentication.class);
    }

}
```

**Dont forget to add the AuthenticationProvider to your Spring configuration**